# Prove an integral identity by using a transformation formula

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

We are given an integrable function $f:[0, 1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and a set $A = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | x, y \geq 0, x+y \leq 1 \}$. I need to show that for $\alpha, \beta > 0$ the following holds: $$ \int_A f(x+y) x^{\alpha}y^{\beta}d\lambda^2(x,y) = \int_0^1 y^{\alpha}(1-y)^{\beta}d\lambda (y) \int_0^1 f(x) x^{\alpha + \beta +1}d\lambda (x). $$

We are provided with the hint to use the following map $\phi: [0,1]^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2, \phi(x, y) =(xy, x(1-y)).$ I do not see how to use the hint. It is clear that in addition to $f$ all other functions that one finds in the integrals on both sides are integrable on the set $A$ and their product as well. Thus, once one can figure out how to separate the variables, the claim will follow by using the Fubini theorem.

Can somebody provide some insight or a solution proposal? Thanks.

Comment: What book is this from? Are you sure there are no typos?

Comment: I corrected a typo. There is no other one. Nevertheless, I suspect that $f$ might be a 2 variable function in order to compose it somehow with $\phi. $ But I am not sure. Anyway, it should go in the direction of changing variables via a transformation by a bijective function such as $\phi. $ As a result the determinant of the jacobian in absolute value should appear in the integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transformation $(x,y)\mapsto \left(x+y,\frac{x}{x+y}\right)=(u,v)$ maps $A$ to $(0,1)^2$ bijectively and has inverse $(u,v)\mapsto(uv,u(1-v))=(x,y)$. Moreover, $$\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)}=-\frac{1}{x+y}=-\frac{1}{u}$$ Therefore, $$\begin{eqnarray*}\iint_{A}f(x+y)x^{\alpha}y^{\beta}\mathrm{d}A&=&\iint_{(0,1)^2}f(u)(uv)^{\alpha}\left[u(1-v)\right]^{\beta}u\mathrm{d}A \\ &=& \iint_{(0,1)^2}f(u)u^{\alpha+\beta+1}v^{\alpha}(1-v)^{\beta}\mathrm{d}A \\ &=& \int_0^1 f(x)x^{\alpha+\beta+1}\mathrm{d}x \cdot \int_0^1 x^{\alpha}(1-x)^{\beta}\mathrm{d}x\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: Thanks. Since $|det J|=\frac{1}{u},$ I do not see if you included this. Maybe I am wrong.